# How to compare two different Vim installs?

Tags: vimdiff, installing, compile-vim

Basically, I want to compare which features were enabled when each installation of Vim was compiled. If there's also other significant differences between the two installations, besides their feature-lists, please let me know.

Apple compiled one installation of Vim, the one that came with macOS, and I compiled the other.

I [compiled Vim from source using Git](https://www.vim.org/download.php#unix) with the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git
cd vim/src
make
make install
```

Here's the version information for Apple's installation of Vim: `/usr/bin/vim --version`

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Nov 29 2017 18:37:46)
Included patches: 1-503, 505-680, 682-1283
Compiled by root@apple.com
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +file_in_path    -mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
-arabic          +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
+autocmd         +float           -mouse_urxvt     -tcl
-balloon_eval    +folding         +mouse_xterm     -termguicolors
-browse          -footer          +multi_byte      -terminal
+builtin_terms   +fork()          +multi_lang      +terminfo
+byte_offset     -gettext         -mzscheme        +termresponse
+channel         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +textobjects
+cindent         +iconv           +num64           +timers
-clientserver    +insert_expand   +packages        +title
-clipboard       +job             +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +jumplist        -perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    -keymap          +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +lambda          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        -langmap         +printer         +visual
-conceal         +libcall         -profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python/dyn      +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con      -lua             -rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            +ruby/dyn        +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
-emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xpm
+eval            -mouse_dec       +statusline      -xsmp
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xterm_clipboard
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax          -xterm_save
-farsi           -mouse_netterm   +tag_binary      
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -o vim        -lm -lncurses  -liconv -framework Cocoa
```

Here's the version information for my installation of Vim: `/usr/local/bin/vim --version`

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Sep 12 2018 18:04:14)
macOS version
Included patches: 1-374
Compiled by me@my.home
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +extra_search      +mouse_netterm     +tag_old_static
+arabic            +farsi             +mouse_sgr         -tag_any_white
+autocmd           +file_in_path      -mouse_sysmouse    -tcl
+autochdir         +find_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       +termguicolors
-autoservername    +float             +mouse_xterm       +terminal
-balloon_eval      +folding           +multi_byte        +terminfo
+balloon_eval_term -footer            +multi_lang        +termresponse
-browse            +fork()            -mzscheme          +textobjects
++builtin_terms    -gettext           +netbeans_intg     +timers
+byte_offset       -hangul_input      +num64             +title
+channel           +iconv             +packages          -toolbar
+cindent           +insert_expand     +path_extra        +user_commands
-clientserver      +job               -perl              +vartabs
+clipboard         +jumplist          +persistent_undo   +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +keymap            +postscript        +virtualedit
+cmdline_hist      +lambda            +printer           +visual
+cmdline_info      +langmap           +profile           +visualextra
+comments          +libcall           -python            +viminfo
+conceal           +linebreak         -python3           +vreplace
+cryptv            +lispindent        +quickfix          +wildignore
-cscope            +listcmds          +reltime           +wildmenu
+cursorbind        +localmap          +rightleft         +windows
+cursorshape       -lua               -ruby              +writebackup
+dialog_con        +menu              +scrollbind        -X11
+diff              +mksession         +signs             -xfontset
+digraphs          +modify_fname      +smartindent       -xim
-dnd               +mouse             +startuptime       -xpm
-ebcdic            -mouseshape        +statusline        -xsmp
+emacs_tags        +mouse_dec         -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
+eval              -mouse_gpm         +syntax            -xterm_save
+ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     +tag_binary        
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X -DMACOS_X_DARWIN  -O2   -Wall -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -o vim        -lm -lncurses  -liconv -framework AppKit
```

That's a lot to look through. Is there an easy way to see a list of features my installation supports that Apple's doesn't and a list of features Apple's installation supports that mine doesn't?

I tried doing it with `diff` and `git diff --color-words --no-index`, but neither command really helped. Maybe there's a script that diffs version information for two different Vim installations?

Answer (score 1):

To get a one column list of Vim's compile options you could use this script:

```
 1 #! /bin/bash
 2 
 3 splitme()
 4 {
 5   while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
 6     line4=$(echo $line | perl -p -e 's/ +/ /g')
 7     for one in $line4
 8     do
 9       echo $one
10     done
11   done
12 }
13
14 vim --version | grep '^[+-]' | splitme | sort --key=1.2
```

where

- 14 `grep` filters all lines that start with `+` or `-`
- 14 `splitme` makes one column from four columns
- 14 `sort` sorts the result ignoring column 1 (`+` or `-`)
- 5 read output of grep line by line
- 6 replace all multiple spaces by single spaces
- 7 walk through line by column
- 8 output column

Partial sample output:

```
+statusline
-sun_workshop
+syntax
-tag_any_white
+tag_binary
+tag_old_static
-tcl
```

Then redirect the output to files and `diff` them.

Comment: A slightly more vim only solution: `put= map(split(execute('version'), '\ze[+-]\w\+'), {_,v->matchstr(v, '[-+]\w\+')})|sort/[+-]/`